# Can I combine a variable and a selector in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="top">top
    <div class="middle">middle
        <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    middle</div>
top</div>
<div class="middle">outside middle</div>
```

Is there a way to create a variable for a selector and then use it as part of another selector?  This is what I'm trying to do, but this does't work :

```
$top = $('.top');

$($top + ' .middle').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
});
```

I'm sure I don't need to re-select .top as that's what the variable did, so I'm sure I need to do something with $top, I'm just not sure what.

http://jsfiddle.net/ftXLx/1/

Comment: use $top.find('.middle')

Comment: Selectors are **strings**.

Comment: Also, don't use .click() if you can avoid it. Look at the syntax for .on() for the suggested event hooking method.

Comment: @mori57 I disagree. `click` is a very readable and convenient shortcut and personally I'll use it as long as it's available. Using jQuery is now 50% about shortcuts and ease of typing and reading.

Comment: @mori57, if your content is static, you shouldnt use `.on()` since it is heavier and less perfomant.

Comment: @mori57 When you *need* to hook to dynamically-generated content, then you know it and you don't use the shortcuts.

Comment: My apologies; I just reread the documentation... I was confusing .click() with .live()'s status of deprecation.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I am honestly curious, however, why .on() would be less performant, as .click() is just a shortcut that references `.on('click', handler)` (http://api.jquery.com/click/) ... unless you really screw up the selector ahead of .on()?

Comment: @mori57, This link test the perfomance http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-versus-click/2. However, it is a sligh difference, but when using this format : `$('#parent').on('click', '.target', fn..)` it is way slower since it will check every elements inside `#parent` while `.click()` is a direct event. So on static elements, `.click` is slightly better.

Comment: Sadly, they dont test the equivalent of `$('#Container').on('click', '.input1'...` wich is `$('#Container').find('.input1').click...`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use

```
$('.middle', $top)
```

or

```
$top.find('.middle')
```

You could also have simply combined the selectors, which are strings, with

```
$($top.selector + ' .middle')
```

but this would only be slower and less readable...

Comment: find is quicker than context

Comment: @Neil, the context format is a shorthand for `.find()` in the same way that `$(function(){})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Worrying about the very slight difference in speed is an exercise in premature optimization.

Comment: @Neil because the context internally triggers `find` after few steps in determining that the second arg is context.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
$top.find(".middle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just select it like this:

```
$('.top .middle').click();
```

Comment: In this example, sure, but I'm working on much longer, convoluted parent selector that I'd rather not type out multiple times.